# Why is this recursive map function using all available memory?

Tags: python

I am trying to implement the map function in Python using recursion, running it on Google Colab.

```
def randfun(var):
    return var * 2

def mapr(f, itr):
    if len(itr) == 1:
        return f(itr[0])
    else:
        amendedlist = list(mapr(randfun, f(itr[1:])))
        #print(amendedlist)
        return amendedlist

li = [1,2,3,4,5]
result = mapr(randfun, li)
print(result)
```

The error I'm getting is this: `Your session crashed after using all available RAM`. It produces a bunch of logs, which I can't decrypt, but am happy to reproduce.

Looks like the code is failing to halt the recursion and it goes on infinitely, but again I'm not sure. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: infinite loop crashes execution

Comment: Because `var * 2` actually multiplies the list as such. I.e. `var` is `itr[1:]` and you multiply it by 2, which increases its size, hence the infinite recursion you get.

Comment: `f(itr[1:])` resolves to `randfun([2,3,4,5])` which gives you `[2, 3, 4, 5]*2 == [2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5] ` and so on, i.e. growing `itr` each iteration.

Comment: With some print statements you can see the issue and why `var * 2` doesn't do what you think it does (seemingly): https://ideone.com/DemE1Y

Comment: Doing `map` recursively only complicates things. There are better excercises to study recursion.

Comment: What is the intended behavior of your program? Do you want it to reduce the list to a single value? Or are you trying to double each element of the iterable?

Comment: Yea, that was a very silly mistake on my part, folks. I immediately realized it once I saw it. I'm a little stressed out, so please excuse that super silly mistake lol.

Comment: @VPfB Kinda yea, but I was just following a nice blog I came across online. The very purpose of this exercise was to make the reader implement problems which are instinctively solved by looping, to enable the reader drive home the point. The author also had me implement printing each element of the list using recursion. I have a much better grasp on recursion now. Thnx for your input... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you recurse, you need to pass a shorter list to `mapr()`, e.g. `itr[1:]`. But you're passing `f(itr[1:])` instead. When `itr == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, `f(itr[1:])` is `f([2, 3, 4, 5])` which is `[2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. So the argument is getting shorter, not longer, and you never reach the base case.

The recursion should just pass `itr[1:]`, not `f(itr[1:])` since the arguments to `f()` should be list elements, not the list itself.

Your base case is also wrong. `mapr()` must always return a list, but in the base case you're just returning the result of the function without wrapping it into a list.

It would be best to use an empty list as the base case, so the function works for empty lists.

```
def mapr(f, itr):
    if len(itr) == 0:
        return []
    else:
        amendedlist = [f(itr[0])] + mapr(f, itr[1:])
        #print(amendedlist)
        return amendedlist
```

Comment: I can't believe I made the mistake of passing f(itr[1:]) instead of just itr[1:]...!!!! Had I done this before my colleagues, I would die of embarrassment. Also my "else" case has a mistake. Alright, I need to calm down a little. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
def randfun(var):
    return var * 2

def mapr(f, itr):
    if len(itr) == 1:
        return [f(itr[0])]
    amendedlist = [f(itr[0])] + mapr(f, itr[1:])
    return amendedlist

li = [1,2,3,4,5]
result = mapr(randfun, li)
print(result) #[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```